# Raspberry pi with NRF24

Tags: spi, nrf24l01

I've tried building a few libraries from source; they compile fine, but the receiving pi gets no data. I found [this post describing similar issues](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77290/nrf24l01-only-correctly-retrieving-status-and-config-registers/91442?noredirect=1#comment146753_91442).

If someone could help me understand the reply that would be a big help. (Namely what I should change in the code to match the pin out of my rpi to nrf24 (ex. they use GPIO 4 and I used 25, but I'm not 100% certain what should be changed within the code).

Comment: Why don't you start with the pinout & code from the q you link to? Apparently, that's working...

Comment: resoldering is a bigger pain than changing a number in the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost at the end of the Python code is the line

```py
nrf = NRF24.NRF24(pi, CE=4, payload=NRF24.NRF24.ACK_PAYLOAD, pad='*', address_bytes=3, crc_bytes=2)
```

Change `CE=4` to `CE=25`

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to using rpis w/ python, If you could point me in the right direction on how to use this with my existing code that would be very helpful.

Comment: @HaydenN I have no idea, I don't know what your existing code is.  I thought you wanted to use the code linked to in the answer you linked.

Comment: I do, i just don't understand where/what you are sending with this. Can/does this function as a library? I'm simply sending a string of information based on joystick input and breaking it up once its been received.

Comment: It is a Python class.  These questions bear no real relationship to the original question.  Perhaps you need to rethink your question to clarify what you are actually asking.  My answer is to the stated question.

Comment: Okay thanks! I titled it broadly because I had multiple questions, and figured if I couldn't be helped with my first simple question, further questions couldn't be answered either.